# Android: Downloading from URL

Tags: java, android

I'm trying an example download code online and I found out that it downloads to about 13KB and then exits. The file is 4 MB. Can anybody help me explain why this is? Here's the code. Thanks.

```
//this is the total size of the file
int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
//variable to store total downloaded bytes
int downloadedSize = 0;

//create a buffer...
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

//now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
    //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
    //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
    //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
    //updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);
    Log.w( "DOWNLOAD" , "progress " + downloadedSize + " / " + totalSize);
```

I noticed that the `totalSize` is `-1` when calling `getContentLength()`...probably because of the missing content length from the header.

Comment: Where are you writing the data to? sdcard? :)

Comment: when content length is `-1`, its **Empty**.

Comment: have you declared `INTERNET` permission in **Manifest**? and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to write file in storage?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. I am writing the data to sdcard. The content length is -1 when I called getContentLength. Yes, I have set the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: This is the path to the downloaded file:  File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/MyDownloaded/") ;

Answer (score 0):

First add both permission     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
 and     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`   in your manifest file and then follow this link(  http://velmuruganandroidcoding.blogspot.in/2013/07/download-image-from-url-to-sd-card-in.html ),
 and make sure that http call must not be on UI Thread. I am sure you will get thing that you need

Comment: Thanks for replying. However, the example you provided did not work. However, it does work with other url. It seems to do with the contentLength being not provided by the server. Is there a way to download this file? Thanks.